# FirstResponderKit - missing objects

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2019

our vendor has recommended us to use your tool to collect data for him. After the installation (version 8.03) we received following errors (warnings):

*The module 'sp_AllNightLog' depends on the missing object 'master.dbo.DatabaseBackup'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists.

The module 'sp_AllNightLog' depends on the missing object 'master.dbo.DatabaseBackup'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists.

The module 'sp_AllNightLog' depends on the missing object 'master.dbo.sp_DatabaseRestore'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists.

The module 'sp_AllNightLog' depends on the missing object 'master.dbo.sp_DatabaseRestore'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists.

The module 'sp_DatabaseRestore' depends on the missing object 'dbo.CommandExecute'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists.*

I verified the master database and I did not find the object mentioned above. Is it OK?

P.S. We are running Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU4) (KB4548597) - 15.0.4033.1 (X64)   Mar 14 2020 16:10:35   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: )
Regards,
Ondrej

Answer (score 3):

The procedure sp_AllNightLog uses Ola Hallengren's scripts to do backup. If you don't plan to use sp_AllNightLog, then it is fine. If you *do* plan to use sp_AllNightLog, then install Ola Hallengren's scripts, which you can find here: https://ola.hallengren.com/

This is documented here: https://www.brentozar.com/sp_allnightlog/